# List files of other device Ionic

Tags: typescript, http, ionic-framework

I am working on a Ionic project. I control a GoPro with my application.
Now, I need to access to the list of all videos.

Videos are contained in this folder : `http://10.5.5.9/videos/DCIM/100GOPRO/` .

I am trying to get the list with the plugin **File**. This is my code:

```
this.file.listDir("http://10.5.5.9/videos/DCIM/100GOPRO/", '').then(
      (files) => {
        for(var i in files)
        console.log(i);
      }
      ).catch(
      (err) => {
        console.log("ERROR : " + err);
      }
    );
```

But when I run my code, I always go in the error case. If someone knows how to fix it and get the list of all the files in the folder, I would be really grateful!

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: @Mathyn I actually got the error message that I defined in my **catch**

Comment: Yes, so what does the error message say? What is the value of the `err` paramater passed to the catch handler?

Comment: @Mathyn The exact message is `ERROR : [object Object]`

Comment: Change the `console.log` line to this: `console.log(err);` and post the output again please.

Comment: @Mathyn I did it, and the complete output was `[app-scripts] [11:33:45]  console.log: [object Object]` (same as before but without the _ERROR :_ ).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181744/discussion-between-mathyn-and-sebastien-kerroue).

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use the JSON endpoint: http://10.5.5.9/gp/gpMediaList